# how do I crank a remanufactured engine for the first time?

Tags: engine, jeep

Just installed my first long block manufactured engine (360 in a 1987 Jeep j20). Got gas, spark and air. Engine turns over but will not hit to fire. Does a manufactured engine come with timing preset? How do I start the engine for the first time to set the timing?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What will it hit?

Comment: You sure you didn't mix up the firing order?

Comment: Wrong firing order, is a good guess, as is incorrectly connected ignition wiring.  Removing the #1 plug wire and putting a spark plug into it, while cracking the engine, is a quick and easy way to check for spark.  Making sure the spark for #1 is happening at the correct point in the 4 cycles would be next.

Comment: Thank all! Much help. I had triple checked the wiring and firing order according to the repair manual. I suspected timing might be the issue, but did not know how a new crate engine might be set up. Do not want to do anything to mess it up

Answer (score 2):

You need to static time it. Pop the #1 spark plug out. Bring the #1 cylinder to top dead center (TDC). As you are bringing it up to TDC, place your finger (or have someone else do it) over the spark plug hole. If you are coming up on TDC of the compression stroke, you should have a rush of air come out of the spark plug hole. If you don't feel this (it is *very* noticeable), you are at the top of the exhaust stroke and will need to swing the crank over another 360° to come back up to TDC on the compression stroke. Pop the distributor cap and see where the rotor is pointing to. If it is pointing to where the #1 spark plug wire is, you are good to go. If you aren't anywhere close to it, you'll need to pull the distributor and re-time it.

You want the rotor to be *straight up* on the #1 cylinder. This will allow you to get it started. You'll want your timing light nearby so when it does fire, you can fine tune the timing. Ensure you do this rather quickly, as you need to run the engine up to 1800-2000 RPM for around 20 minutes right after startup for break-in. If you don't, you'll lay your cam out flat and destroy it. (I'm sure that part is in the break-in instructions for your long block.)

Comment: This is incorrect -- a four cycle engine has two different TDC points.  They are the compression-to-combustion transition and exhaust-to-intake transition.  The distributor rotor MUST be at the #1 cylinder immediately prior to the compression-to-combustion TDC point.  If it is 180 degrees off, the spark will fire at the top of the exhaust stroke and not do a damned useful thing.

Comment: @JulieinAustin - You are absolutely right. That was my faux pas. Thanks for showing me the error of my ways. I have updated and updated again to explain how to find TDC on the compression stroke.